# Check In after 8am with Java8 Time

Tags: java, java-8, date

I have the following scenario:
I have a check-in kinda app, where after 8am (included) the user is able to check-in again if the user has not checked-in in the meantime between D-1 8AM and D 8AM.

For instance:

LastCheckin -> JAN 28th 08:01AM 
Today -> JAN 29th 07:50AM 
Cannot check-in above

LastCheckin -> JAN 28th 00:50AM 
Today -> JAN 28th 09:10PM 
Can check-in above

LastCheckin -> JAN 28th 07:50AM 
Today -> JAN 28th 09:50AM 
Can check-in above

LastCheckin -> JAN 28th 05:50PM 
Today -> JAN 28th 06:50AM 
Cannot check-in above

My validate function:

```
private Boolean validateLastCheckIn(LocalDateTime lastCheckinDate){
        LocalTime checkinTime = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plusHours(8);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime todayCheckinTime = LocalDateTime.of(today, checkinTime);

        //if trying to checkIn before limit, but on the same day (eg. after 12am)
        if(lastCheckinDate.getDayOfYear() == todayCheckinTime.getDayOfYear()){
            return lastCheckinDate.isAfter(todayCheckinTime);
        }else{
            //if its some other day in the past check
            LocalDate yesterdayCheckIn = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
            LocalDateTime yesterdayCheckinTime = LocalDateTime.of(yesterdayCheckIn, checkinTime);
            return lastCheckinDate.isBefore(yesterdayCheckinTime);
        }
    }
```

I've got two questions, is there any other better option than doing this comparison? Are there any gaps or flaws doing this way that I may have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are asking us to test your method.

Comment: This seems more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I just wanted to make sure there is no better option than The one I provided

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll post there then

Comment: Once you’ve posted to Code Review, please leave a link here. I believe I have a couple of (minor) comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it that way:

```
    private Boolean canCheckin(LocalDateTime nextValidCheckinTime){
        return timeFactory.now().isAfter(nextValidCheckinTime);
    }

    private LocalDateTime nextValidCheckinTime(LocalDateTime lastCheckinDate){
        LocalTime checkinTime = LocalTime.of(7, 59, 59);

        if (lastCheckinDate.toLocalTime().isBefore(checkinTime)) {
            return lastCheckinDate.withHour(7).withMinute(59).withSecond(0);
        } else {
            return lastCheckinDate.plusDays(1).withHour(7).withMinute(59).withSecond(59);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution. Not sure why you want to split at 7:59:59 rather than 8:00:00.

Answer (score 5):

the requirements can be simplified like this: the last check in datetime needs to be 24 hours after yesterday at 8 AM.
so the method can be written like this

```
private Boolean validateLastCheckIn(LocalDateTime lastCheckinDate){
    LocalTime checkinTime = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plusHours(8);
    LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
    LocalDateTime yesterdayAt8AM = LocalDateTime.of(yesterday, checkinTime);

    // between(start, end)
    return ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(yesterdayAt8AM, lastCheckinDate) > 24*60;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that once I get home! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I made myself clear. If the user has checked-in before 'yesterdayAt8AM' she/he can check-in. The only constraint is, the user cannot checkin if he is in between D-1 8AM and D 8AM. Thanks!

Comment: `return ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(yesterdayAt8AM, lastCheckinDate) > 24 * 60 ||
                lastCheckinDate.isBefore(yesterdayAt8AM);`

Comment: Does that make sense?